# Java Factorial using GUI only returns the first output

Tags: java, user-interface, factorial

I have a program which should generate the factorial of any given number n.

When the user enters a number, the output is the factorial for every number entered after that into the calculator. 
The code compiles fine but the calculator will not calculate any factorial except for the first.
As i can't use recursion for solving this problem please post only answers without using recursion.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment7
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int number1;
int factorial = 1;
String message;

number1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer that you would like factored (Type \"1\" to stop) : "));


for(int i = 1; i <= number1; i++)
{
factorial = factorial * i;


}



do
 {
message = String.format("The factorial of %d is: %d", number1, factorial);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
number1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer that you would like factored (Type \"1\" to stop) : "));

 }  
while(number1 != 1);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
for(int i = 1; i <= number1; i++)
{
  factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

needs to be repeated for each input.

I suggest that your GF put this into a method that can be called and the method will return the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment7
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
int number1;
int factorial = 1;
String message;

number1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer that you would like factored (Type \"1\" to stop) : "));


for(int i = 1; i <= number1; i++)
{
factorial = factorial * i;


}



do
 {
message = String.format("The factorial of %d is: %d", number1, factorial);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
number1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer that you would like factored (Type \"1\" to stop) : "));
factorial = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= number1; i++)
{
factorial = factorial * i;
}
 }  
while(number1 != 1);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the number and the factorial to get the right factorial.

Also i would consider to use a head-controlled loop. Because it's easier to understand what is going on. Also maybe don't put the Inputdialog and the Parsing of the string to int into one line, it makes it a lot easier to handle wrong user-inputs, what you also should be doing. 
Here my solution:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    class Assignment7 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int number1 = 0;
            int factorial = 1;
            String message;

            while (number1 != 1) {
                String positiveInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a positive integer that you would like factored (Type \"1\" to stop) : ");
    // You could check if there was a user-input and also later check if it's a number.
                if (positiveInteger.length() > 0) {
                    number1 = Integer.parseInt(positiveInteger);
                }

                for (int i = 1; i <= number1; i++) {
                    factorial = factorial * i;
                }

                message = String.format("The factorial of %d is: %d", number1, factorial);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

                //Reset everything
                number1 = 0;
                factorial = 1;
                message = "";
            }
        }
    }
```